# Converting a python package into a single importable file

Tags: python, python-module

Is there a way to convert a python package, i.e. is a folder of python files, into a single file that can be copied and then directly imported into a python script without needing to run any extra shell commands? I know it is possible to zip all of the files and then unzip them from python when they are needed, but I'm hoping that there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: use `setup.py` to make it an actual package ... and then `pip install git+https://my.github/project.git` (or `pip install myPackage.tar`)

Comment: You can import an entire directory as a Python module, all you need is an ```__init__.py``` file in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

It's not totally clear what the question is.  I could interpret it two ways.

---

If you are looking to manage the symbols from many modules in a more organized way:

You'll want to put an `__init__.py` file in your directory and make it a package.  In it you can define the symbols for your package, and create a graceful `import packagename` behavior.  Details on [packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

---

If you are looking to make your code portable to another environment:

One way or the other, the package needs to be accessible in whatever environment it is run in.  That means it either needs to be installed in the python environment (likely using `pip`), copied into a location that is in a subdirectory relative to the running code, or in a directory that is listed in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

The most straightforward way to package up code and make it portable is to use `setuptools` to create a portable package that can be installed into any python environment.  The manual page for [Packaging Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) gives the details of how to go about building a package archive, and optionally uploading to PyPi for public distribution.   If it is for private use, the resulting archive can be passed around without uploading it to the public repository.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your input. I guess that I'm not really being clear enough. What I really want is to make a single file that I can import without having to install. I just want to ship a single file that can be imported directly. Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: You could try to put all you need in a large `.py` file, but even then, you'd need to give specific instructions to the enduser on where to put it so that it could be imported.  Different environments will give you headaches.  It would be easier all around to pass them an archive file and ask that they `pip install`.