# How to import nested modules inside a folder in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, package

I'm having a similar but different issue from the other posts I've seen on here: I'm trying to import a module from a nested module, but even though the python linter picks up everything fine I can't execute the file because of an import error, module not found.

```
ParentFolder /
|__ContainerFolder
   |__ __init__.py
   |__ Camera/
       |__ __init__.py
       |__ CameraService.py
       |__ Data.py
   |__ Settings /
       |__ __init__.py
       |__ SettingService.py
       |__ Handler /
           |__ __init__.py
           |__ Handle.py
       |__ Models /
           |__ __init__.py
           |__  Setting.py
```

What I want is to import `Data.py` inside of `Handle.py`

I have tried:

```py
from ContainerFolder.Camera.Data import DataClass
```

The linter says it's fine, and the autofill in VS Code gives me type-ahead, however, at execution I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` for ContainerFolder module. <s>I have an `__init__.py` in all the directories so what am I missing to make that a module to import from?</s>

***edit***

So `CameraService.py` and `SettingService.py` are both Tornado APIs, since they are both executing as *main* how would one be able to share modules between the two? ie `Data.py` with modules under the Settings directory or `Setting.py` within modules under the Camera directory?

Comment: Is your `__init__.py` file  at the `Camera` level really named `__inti__.py`?

Comment: Since you are using VS code, then please also check you are in the right directory by using this line of code 'os.getcwd()'. You will need to import 'os' module using 'import os'.

Comment: which one is your execution script ? run the execution script from the parent directory  path

Comment: Where is the file that contains `from ContainerFolder.Camera.Data import DataClass` located?

Comment: There is an executable in the Settings and Camera. The one in Settings needs to pull in the Data,py object.

Comment: @AliSajjad it's in: `/home/project/ParentFolder/Container/Settings/Handler`

Comment: @AliSajjad I already commented what `os.getcdw()` outputs and I would have to disagree. One imports python modules into other python modules, which is specifically stated via `import`, so there isn't anything wrong with the wording.

Answer (score -1):

Try converting the file into a package like here

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/refactoring-convert.html

or here

[Converting a python package into a single importable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56961601/converting-a-python-package-into-a-single-importable-file)

Comment: this is not a solution related to the problem